# Disable Jooq tip of the day

Tags: java, jooq

Is there any way to disable jooQ from printing the tip of the day?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you can see by looking at the [source code](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/blob/main/jOOQ/src/main/java/org/jooq/impl/DefaultRenderContext.java#L1040), you can disable it by defining the system property `org.jooq.no-tips` to `true`, for example on the command line, in a properties file, or in your code:

```
System.setProperty("org.jooq.no-tips", "true");
```

Comment: That's actually one of the tips of the day :) *"Don't want tips? Use the -Dorg.jooq.no-tips=true system property"*

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using jOOQ inside of Spring, and if so put the following line into your `application.properties`. It turns the tip of the day and the logo off

```
logging.level.org.jooq.Constants=off
```